# How to get console.log working in browser when using socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a basic socket.io code embedded in an HTML page. It looks like the client can connect to the server with no problem since the service side script confirm it.

But for some reason, `console.log` in the browser does not work and does not log the message.

Here is the client.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    socket.on('connection', function () {
        console.log('Connected to server');
    });
</script>
```

and the server.js

```
let io = require('socket.io').listen(process.env.port || 5000);

io.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('client connected');

});
```

However, when I take the `console.log` outside of `socket.on`, the console.log does work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    console.log('Connected to server');
    socket.on('connection', function () {
        console.log('Connected to server');
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Console.log should work fine in a browser ... if you hit F12 and enable Developer Tools....

Comment: Try `console.log('Connected to server')` instead. Apostrophes, not backticks.

Comment: @paulsm4 I did , can not see any log

Comment: @ceejayoz changed it and same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the socket.io docs, it looks like the event you need might actually be `connect` and not `connected`.

Your console log isn't firing, because socket.io isn't ever firing an event called connection.

Try:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log(`Connected to server`);
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket

Comment: I used connect. Connected is a string

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the event you listen to. See my edited answer for clarification

Comment: When you bind an event listener using that syntax, you need to get the event name correct, otherwise the function you define won't execute. In this case, the object that `io.connect` returns, has a specific set of events, one of which being `connect`.

Comment: Yep. The socket.io object won't trigger an event that matches `connection`